# Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() returns 2 when create order from quote

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

When i am creating an order from quote, in onload Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() returns me the value 2.

but the form is in create mode, so should return 1.

Answer (score 2):

When you "win" a quote and a Sales Order is generated, there is no *Create* state presented by the UI - the system creates the new record in the background and then displays it. When you are presented with the new Sales Order through this process, it already has a record ID so `Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType()` will return `2`, which is the *Update* state.

The only way to get the *Create* state (`1`) from `Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType()` would be to manually create a Sales Order. However, if you do this you will lose much of the convenience the system does automatically for you, such as copying over all fields with the same name (essentially duplicating the Quote data into the the new Sales Order).